# ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables when running Merge Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-merge

[image]

I am executing a merge query to update 2 columns in a table, but I get the following error "ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables.

When I execute the merge query but I have already used a partition by and where rn=1 in the using clause to pick up only the non-duplicate records from source, but Oracle still throws the error.

What can I do to resolve this?

```
MERGE
/*+ parallel(A) enable_parallel_dml*/
INTO
(
  SELECT
    PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
    AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
    AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
    SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
    SRC_CREATED_DATE,
    SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
  FROM
    EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP
)
A USING
(
SELECT
  PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
  AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
  AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
  SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
  SRC_CREATED_DATE,
  SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
      AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
      AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
      SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
      SRC_CREATED_DATE,
      SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
      AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY, AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY, SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
      SRC_CREATED_DATE, SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
    FROM
      EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP_FRS_356
  )
WHERE
  rn = 1
)
B ON
(
  A.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY = B.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY AND
  A.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY    = B.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY AND
  A.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY = B.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY AND
  A.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID         = B.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET
    A.SRC_CREATED_DATE     = B.SRC_CREATED_DATE,
    A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE = B.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
  WHERE
    A.SRC_CREATED_DATE      <> B.SRC_CREATED_DATE
  OR A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE <> B.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE;
   COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have already used a partition by and where rn=1 in the using clause to pick up only the non-duplicate records from source, but Oracle still throws the error.

Your

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
      AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY, AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY, SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
      SRC_CREATED_DATE, SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
```

with a filter `rn=1`
removes duplicates by 6 columns, while you are using 4 columns in `ON()` clause.
Moreover you are using another filter to filter rows for update.

The easiest way to get what you want is to filter needed data in `USING` clause:

```sql
MERGE
/*+ parallel(A) enable_parallel_dml*/
INTO
(
  SELECT
    PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
    AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
    AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
    SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
    SRC_CREATED_DATE,
    SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
  FROM
    EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP
)
A USING
(
SELECT
  PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
  AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
  AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
  SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
  SRC_CREATED_DATE,
  SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      BB.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
      BB.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
      BB.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
      BB.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
      BB.SRC_CREATED_DATE,
      BB.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( 
         PARTITION BY BB.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
                      BB.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY, 
                      BB.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY, 
                      BB.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID
         ORDER BY ROWNUM /*?*/ 
         ) AS rn
    FROM
      EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP_FRS_356 BB
     ,EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP AA
    WHERE
      AA.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY = BB.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY AND
      AA.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY    = BB.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY AND
      AA.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY = BB.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY AND
      AA.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID         = BB.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID
      AND (
          AA.SRC_CREATED_DATE     <> BB.SRC_CREATED_DATE
       OR AA.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE <> BB.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
      )
  )
WHERE
  rn = 1
)
B ON
(
  A.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY = B.PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY AND
  A.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY    = B.AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY AND
  A.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY = B.AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY AND
  A.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID         = B.SCHEDULE_LINE_ID
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET
    A.SRC_CREATED_DATE     = B.SRC_CREATED_DATE,
    A.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE = B.SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE;
```

As you can see I filtered rows you don't need in the `USING` clause, so you don't need `WHERE` clause in `UPDATE SET` and removed duplicates by 4 columns used for matching

Comment: the query which you suggested is running for a very long time is there a way to tune it as were are updating 118M records using the above logic

Comment: You need to provide more info: execution plan, sql monitor, tables ddl and statistics, etc

Comment: I have added the execution plan for the using clause alone , as running it alone is taking more than 2 hours by now and it has not completed as of yet

Comment: Ok, first of all, replace `order by rownum` with just `order by null`, it will remove extra operation `couny`. Second you need to gather table statistics for both tables, since your explain plan shows 1 row.

Comment: I have replaced the order with null and gathered stats on both tables. Please find the latest explain plan attached.

Comment: Ok, I see... 22 mln rows and 1.2bln rows... Try to add parallel hint for this `select` and check how long does it work. Then add `aa.rowid as rid ` into inner view in using clause and `rid` into top level main select of using clause and replace on() with `on(a.rowid=b.rid)` and check resulted execution plan of it

Comment: @ Sayan Malakshinov I have added the explain plan after adding parallel hint's however I am unable to add the row id as per what you have mentioned, it is throwing the following error "cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table"

Comment: As I said previously `aa.rowid as rid` must be in the inner view, not top level select. On top level select must be `rid`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232457/discussion-between-karthik-and-sayan-malakshinov).

Comment: is there any other alternative way to simplify the query? like using max ()

Comment: I said to replace whole `on(...) ` clause with `on(a.rowid=b.rid)` you don't need previous 4 conditions since they were filtered already in using clause

Comment: And to be honest, that's another question and you need to create another topic for the query optimization